# Cannot get SQL Query to work with SafeSqlLiteral function

Tags: sql, vb.net

I have a function SafeSqlLiteral, found online. It's a function to prevent SQL injection attacks. I want to use this function inside my SQL query like so:

```vb
Dim com As String = "SELECT * FROM Person WHERE " &  
                     SafeSqlLiteral(SearchCriteria, 2)
```

SearchCriteria being user input. I want the user to be able to enter: strState LIKE 'M%' and show all the records matching a state like Maine. It feels like this would work. (SELECT * FROM Person WHERE strState LIKE 'M%')

I'm getting a whole bunch of errors (probably too many to post on here, but will post them if needed), and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make my query work with the SafeSqlLiteral function.

Here is the SafeSqlLiteral function:

```vb
Public Function SafeSqlLiteral(theValue As System.Object,
                               theLevel As System.Object) As String

        Dim strValue As String = DirectCast(theValue, String)
        Dim intLevel As Integer = CInt(theLevel)

        If strValue IsNot Nothing Then
            If intLevel > 0 Then
                strValue = strValue.Replace("'", "''")
                strValue = strValue.Replace("--", "")
                strValue = strValue.Replace("[", "[[]")
                strValue = strValue.Replace("%", "[%]")
            End If
            If intLevel > 1 Then
                Dim myArray As String() = New String() {"xp_ ", "update ", "insert ", "select ", "drop ", "alter ",
        "create ", "rename ", "delete ", "replace "}
                Dim i As Integer = 0
                Dim i2 As Integer = 0
                Dim intLenghtLeft As Integer = 0
                For i = 0 To myArray.Length - 1
                    Dim strWord As String = myArray(i)
                    Dim rx As New Regex(strWord, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
                    Dim matches As MatchCollection = rx.Matches(strValue)
                    i2 = 0
                    For Each match As Match In matches
                        Dim groups As GroupCollection = match.Groups
                        intLenghtLeft = groups(0).Index + myArray(i).Length + i2
                        strValue = strValue.Substring(0, intLenghtLeft - 1) + "&nbsp;" + strValue.Substring(strValue.Length - (strValue.Length - intLenghtLeft), strValue.Length - intLenghtLeft)
                        i2 += 5
                    Next
                Next
            End If
            Return strValue
        Else
            Return strValue
        End If

    End Function
```

Thanks in advance for anyone helping me solve this problem! It's greatly appreciated!

Comment: if you can post the output of the string from a call to SafeSqlCriteria function  it might be quite easy to figure this one out. Having said that, its probably easier to do the above by using bind variables and parameters and prevent sql injection.

Comment: What DBProvider are you using?  That thing ought not be needed at all.  `a whole bunch of errors` is just too vague and too broad.

Comment: A parameterized query would be much easier than using that method.  That's just unnecessary extra code.  And what if the value of a field legitimately has two dashes (--) or a percent sign?